# Node.js application deployment in production?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, tomcat, wamp

I want to build/bundle and deploy the node.js, express in the production server such as Apache, Wamp or Tomcat.

My node.js application has pure back end logic such as API end point, DB connectivity etc.

This will serve for the API request from out separate Front End application.
FE appln built and deployed independently in the server. It works as expected.

But didn't a idea for proper deployment of node.js backend application.

Currently running the Node.js application as below

## server.bat

```
rem node ./server.js
nodemon ./server.js PORT=7071
```

We will execute the server.bat file to start the server and it executes as expected. But its getting terminated frequently. So expectly a proper deployment something like build, build and deploy the code in the server.

**Do we need to any other task runners like Grunt/Babel for bundling?**

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to bundle your code for running node.js applications on the server. You can use Babel, but the only reason you would need to use it would be if you are using ECMAScript features that are not yet available in your version of the  node.js runtime.

If you do decide to use Babel to enable features like `import` syntax, Babel will handle "transpiling" your code, which involves changing your code to rewrite the features that are not yet available in your node runtime to equivalent code that is compatible. This is all optional, and more recent versions of node support most of the popular new JavaScript features.

What you are looking for is a process manager, something that will make sure the node process restarts if it stops running and basically help you manage the running server. One popular option is PM2 (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). PM2 also has additional features for monitoring metrics and assisting with deployment.